# React doesn't render unless I add a console.log() instruction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these two React components:

```
class Record extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
        return (
      <div className="animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3">
        {
          showMessage && currentRecord &&
          <Alert />
        }
        <div className="row">
          <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12">
            <AttrActions module={this.props.module} app={this.props.app} set={currentCatalog} record={currentRecord} accessCase="controls"/>
            <AttrForm
              fields_meta={alertedFieldsMeta}
              currentForm={this.getCurrentForm()}
              originalForm={this.state.originalForm}
              reportChange={this.catchChange}
              fetchList={fetchList}
              hierarchy={this.state.hierarchy}
              catalogsList={catalogsList}
              fetchRecord={fetchRecord}
              searchInCatalog={searchInCatalog}
            />
          </CardBox>
        </div>
        <div className="crud-footer">
          <ControlButtons />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AttrActions extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    switch (this.props.module) {
      case 'Inventory': {
        return (
          <InventoryActions {...this.props} />
        );
      }
      default: {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that component `AttrActions` is never rendered unless I add a `console.log()` instruction in component `Record`, like this:

```
return (
      <div className="animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3">
        {
          showMessage && currentRecord &&
          <Alert />
        }
        <div className="row">
          <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12">
            {console.log('here')}
            <AttrActions module={this.props.module} app={this.props.app} set={currentCatalog} record={currentRecord} accessCase="controls"/>
            <AttrForm
              fields_meta={alertedFieldsMeta}
              currentForm={this.getCurrentForm()}
              originalForm={this.state.originalForm}
              reportChange={this.catchChange}
              fetchList={fetchList}
              hierarchy={this.state.hierarchy}
              catalogsList={catalogsList}
              fetchRecord={fetchRecord}
              searchInCatalog={searchInCatalog}
            />
          </CardBox>
        </div>
        <div className="crud-footer">
          <ControlButtons />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Only in this case, I get the `console.log(this.props)` in the console. If I don't add this instruction, component `AttrActions` is never rendered.

**EDIT**

I found that when I put each component on different `CardBox`, the problem disappears, but I would like them both to be contained together:

```
return (
      <div className="animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3">
        {
          showMessage && currentRecord &&
          <Alert />
        }
        <div className="row">
          <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12">
            <AttrActions module={this.props.module} app={this.props.app} set={currentCatalog.name} record={currentRecord} accessCase="controls"/>
          </CardBox>
          <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12">
            <AttrForm
              fields_meta={alertedFieldsMeta}
              currentForm={this.getCurrentForm()}
              originalForm={this.state.originalForm}
              reportChange={this.catchChange}
              fetchList={fetchList}
              hierarchy={this.state.hierarchy}
              catalogsList={catalogsList}
              fetchRecord={fetchRecord}
              searchInCatalog={searchInCatalog}
            />
          </CardBox>
        </div>
        <div className="crud-footer">
          <ControlButtons />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: just use if statement instead of switch

Comment: @demkovych Nope, exactly the same. I expected it because `console.log(this.props)` is before `switch` statement.

Comment: Could you please put you code on codesanbox.io so we can see it running?

Comment: Could you please send how you are using < Record > ?

Comment: Never rendered? or never **re**-rendered?

Comment: @BrianThompson Component `AttrActions` never renders. All other components in that `div` render with no problem